# Bootstrap-Carousel not working after removing Item

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to remove the active carousel item through `JQuery`. But after removing the item no other item is showing under carousel-inner class. My code is as follows:

```
$('#showLocationDiv').bind('click', function(evt){
$('#location-carousel').carousel('next');
$(evt.target).closest('.item').remove();});
```

Please help me, and thanks in advance.

Complete code is here:

**`HTML` part**

```
<div class="location-carousel">
                    <div id="location-carousel" data-ride="carousel" class="carousel slide text-align-center">
                        <!-- Carousel Slides / Quotes -->
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                                                            <div data-lng="-73.95972" data-lat="45.3497926" style="padding: 0;text-align: center;" class="col-sm-12 item">
                                <div class="pad-t-b-10"><span id="locShowDivInner_1"> 45,l Canada city road, canada city, Ca, Canada, (265) 894-6847 </span>
                                    <br>
                                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs mar-t-10 editLocation " data-toggle="popover" data-locid="4" data-order="1" id="locationOrderId_1" data-original-title="" title="">   
                                        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> 
                                    </button>

                                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs mar-l-10 mar-t-10 deleteLocation" data-locid="4" data-order="1">
                                        <i class="fa fa-times white-color"></i> 
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                                            <div data-lng="80.25742730000002" data-lat="13.0061588" style="padding: 0;text-align: center;" class="col-sm-12 item">
                                <div class="pad-t-b-10"><span id="locShowDivInner_6"> Latice Bridge Rd Adyar , Chennai, TN, India,  </span>
                                    <br>
                                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs mar-t-10 editLocation " data-toggle="popover" data-locid="35" data-order="6" id="locationOrderId_6" data-original-title="" title="">  
                                        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> 
                                    </button>

                                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs mar-l-10 mar-t-10 deleteLocation" data-locid="35" data-order="6">
                                        <i class="fa fa-times white-color"></i> 
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                                            <div data-lng="88.42341999999996" data-lat="22.57736" style="padding: 0;text-align: center;" class="col-sm-12 item active">
                                <div class="pad-t-b-10"><span id="locShowDivInner_5"> saltlake bazar more, Bidhan Nagar, WB, India,(985) 577-4558</span> 
                                    <br>
                                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs mar-t-10 editLocation " data-toggle="popover" data-locid="34" data-order="5" id="locationOrderId_5" data-original-title="" title="">  
                                        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> 
                                    </button>

                                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs mar-l-10 mar-t-10 deleteLocation" data-locid="34" data-order="5">
                                        <i class="fa fa-times white-color"></i> 
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                                        </div>  
                        <!-- Carousel Buttons Next/Prev -->
                        <div class="control-box">
                            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#location-carousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
                            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#location-carousel" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
```

**`JS` part:**

```
$('#showLocationDiv').bind('click', function(evt){
if( $(evt.target).hasClass('deleteLocation')){$('#location-carousel').carousel('next');$(evt.target).closest('.item').remove();alert('Loaction deleted successfully');}});
```

Comment: Can you please provide some more code or http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: Please share some code for us to go thru. Also, note that once you remove the active carousel item, make sure that you add **active** class to the next available item. One item must always have this class for the carousel to work.

Comment: @Vijeth Thanks a lot I have added active class to the next available item and it started to work fine. Again thanks a lot.

Comment: @Debajyoti I have posted my response as the answer. Please accept it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note that once you remove the active carousel item, make sure that you add active class to the next available item. One item must always have this class for the carousel to work.